# will be initialized after [-Wreorder]

Tags: c++, g++

When I compile my files I get this warning :

```
In file included from AsyncSQL.cpp:8:0:
AsyncSQL.h: In constructor 'CAsyncSQL::CAsyncSQL()':
AsyncSQL.h:192:10: warning: 'CAsyncSQL::m_iCopiedQuery' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
   int    m_iCopiedQuery;
      ^
```

Here is my AsyngSQL.H   http://pastebin.com/u72kyuq7
So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your code here, instead of a link to somewhere else.

Comment: Please don't ever use pastebin again. Stack Overflow is where your code goes. Maybe github too for huge huge huuuuuge pieces, but not pastebin. The link is totally dead now and I have no idea of knowing what your code was, yet the answer seems to pertain directly to me.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The problem is the order in which you initialize members in the initializer list on line 22,

```
_SQLResult(): pSQLResult(NULL), uiNumRows(0),
              uiAffectedRows(0), uiInsertID(0)
```

These should appear in the same order as they appear in the class definition. For example:

```
class test {
  test(): foo(1), bar(2) { }
  int  foo;
  long bar;
};
```

Comment: Please give me the exact line to be modified function.
I am a beginner in c ++ and I can not tell.

Comment: The constructor for your `CAsyncSQL` class is not defined in the header file. Can I see your `AsyncSQL.cpp`?

Comment: Here is:  http://pastebin.com/U9irZNha

Comment: This is the right order for the initializer list in the `CAsyncSQL` constructor

`CAsyncSQL::CAsyncSQL()
        : m_stHost(""), m_stUser(""), m_stPassword(""), m_stDB(""), m_stLocale(""),
        m_iMsgCount(0), m_iPort(0), m_bEnd(false),
        m_hThread(0),
        m_mtxQuery(NULL), m_mtxResult(NULL),
        m_iQueryFinished(0), m_ulThreadID(0), m_bConnected(false), m_iCopiedQuery(0)
{ }`

That's on line 13 in AsyncSQL.cpp

Comment: But you maked a little mistake :   m_iCopiedQuery(0) { }         must be           m_iCopiedQuery(0)

Comment: Is this a purely stylistic issue or could it actually cause runtime problems?

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan: A little late to the party but:  It can cause runtime problems.  Consider `struct test { int foo; int bar; test() : bar(1), foo(bar+1) {} };`.  `foo` will be initialized *before* bar, so it will have an indeterminate value.  (The reason the initializations are in declaration order is because the destructors have to be called in reverse declaration order (different constructors could have different orders), and we want the destruction to be the reverse order of destruction.)

Comment: Even withOUT the code, because all the OP's pastebin links are broken, this answer still solved my problem. The _key takeaway_: **initializer list members "should appear in the same order as they appear in the class definition"**. Thank you!